# Running pub install. Please ensure Git is correctly installed. Mac OSX

Tags: dart

When putting git: dependency in the pubspec.  I get the following error:

'Running pub install' has encountered a problem.
...
...
...
Please ensure Git is correctly installed.

My git is installed at version 1.8.0 that I can access via the terminal on my Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just navigate to the dart project folder and run `pub install` on the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that git's path is loaded to `PATH` only on terminal start up. Terminal does this by running a file `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` that often exports the paths to commonly used programs. As a consequence, a GUI app such as the Dart Editor can't 'see' git as it doesn't run this start up file.

There is a way to make certain paths visible to all applications though.

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x/277034

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a file:

```
/etc/paths.d/git
```

With the following contents:

```
/usr/local/git/bin/
```

If your Git installation is located somewhere else, then use the path accordingly.